# Can I get the user name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, users

I would like to use the user name of a logged in user in JavaScript without server side implementation.

Since I'm using a cache plugin (WP Super Cache), I don't want to place a user name into the generated HTML output of WordPress. But I would like to use it to fill a contact form, if the user is already logged in.

Is there a way without a separate AJAX request?

Comment: Without AJAX? No.

Comment: FWIW W3 Total Cache appears to support something like this using special tags in the template: https://www.justinsilver.com/technology/wordpress/w3-total-cache-fragment-caching-wordpress/

Comment: @Jacob Peattie: ... but I can use the `wp-settings-...` cookie, to get the WordPress user Id. ;-)

Comment: Only if the user has been to `/wp-admin`, and you still need an AJAX request to get the user name.

Comment: Can you clarify why you're trying to avoid a server-side implementation? If it's simply to avoid the caching, but you're otherwise able to make PHP changes, you can pass the username to your Javascript using this technique: https://blog.wplauncher.com/pass-php-values-to-a-javascript-file-in-wordpress/